# Storing JSON data in jQuery cookie after successful AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cookies

I am trying to store JSON data I am retrieving via AJAX in a jQuery cookie. I am using the following plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to achieve this. The plugin works great when I am storing non JSON objects.

I can see it is working perfectly when storing simple strings. However, when I try to store my JSON data that I get from my AJAX call, the cookie is not saving. Here is my relevant code:

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://www.example.com/sandbox/BF/context/messagesNew.php",
            success: function(data) {
            
                //This works
                $.cookie('Name', 'John');
                console.log($.cookie('Name'));
              
                //This does not work
                $.cookie("test-data", JSON.stringify(data));
                var myJSONCookie = JSON.parse($.cookie("test-data"));
                console.log(myJSONCookie); // Returns error in console: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
            }
        });
```

I have tried several other snippets of code but none have worked properly. I do not even think that `test-data` is being created as a cookie because when I logged the entire `$.cookie();` to the console, my cookie called `Name` appears but `test-data` does not.

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `console.log(data)` to see what your `data` variable is.  My guess is that it's `undefined` or something that doesn't stringify properly

Comment: @jfriend00 I did this and it is my JSON. I double checked this because I thought the same thing. Any other thoughts on what it could be?

Comment: Please post what the data looks like.  Also, try taking the `-` out of the cookie name in case that is messing anything up.  And, did you look in the debugger to see what cookie values there are there?

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried removing the `-` in the cookie name but that did not solve the issue unfortunately. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I log the `data` being returned with my AJAX call: http://imgur.com/q6tGLzs

Comment: If `JSON.parse()` returns a SyntaxError that is because you did not give it valid JSON to parse.  What is the result of `JSON.stringify(data)`?  What is `console.log($.cookie("test-data"));`.

Comment: @jfriend00 when I run `console.log($.cookie("test-data"));` I am receiving `undefined` in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70193/discussion-between-three3-and-jfriend00).

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` show?  Can you see the trend here.  You look at each stage of your code to try to figure out where things go wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` shows my JSON. Here is a pic: http://imgur.com/W9pUZJG

Comment: Perhaps it has exceeded a length limit for the cookie.  Most browsers limit a total cookie per site to about 4k.  It looks like you're trying to put an entire HTML document into the cookie.  You probably need to rethink that.  There are larger storage limits for LocalStorage.

Comment: @jfriend00 The JSON is about 9MB. What could I use to store it in? What I am trying to achieve is this: Once the JSON file is initially downloaded for the first time, each subsequent request will reuse the JSON initially downloaded. Only if the user manually requests an update will I refetch the JSON. I tried using `cache: true` in my AJAX call but that did not work. I also looked int HTML5 localStorage but the storage limits are not large enough. Any other suggestions? Thanks so much for your help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are trying to put in your cookie is way too large for a cookie.  Cookies are limited to around 4k.  Part of this is for storage management and part of this is because every request to a server sends all the cookies with it.  If you stored a 9MB cookie, you'd be sending an extra 9MB with every single page or ajax request to that server which would obviously be a disaster.

LocalStorage is another option that has larger storage limits, is still partitioned per domain and does not have the issue with sending large things to the server on every request.

If LocalStorage is not large enough also, then you can start considering only modern browsers that contain something like IndexedDB which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

You probably need a different design approach.  We could probably help with ideas for a different approach, but would have to understand the overall problem you're trying to solve and why you need to store 9MB locally and cannot just retrieve it from the server when needed in the future?

Comment: I added info about IndexedDB which might be an option if you can live with the browser support.

Comment: Thanks for all of the info and help. I have found a solution that works for me. I simply will create a file with PHP that stores the JSON on the first AJAX call. Each subsequent call will then use the JSON file created on my server. I will simply use the `$.cookie` to keep track of whether or not I can use the server JSON file or if I need to fetch the newest info. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @three3 - bingo - caching on the server.